# Mismatched RAM across two CPUs - LGA1366 architecture (Westmere)

Tags: memory, motherboard

Firstly, I hope SuperUser is the right place for this server hardware/RAM question.  I wondered if it should be on ServerFault, but I found a Meta question indicating HW questions go here.

I have a Tyan S7012 motherboard, running the LGA1366 architecture.  I have 2 x X5670 2.93ghz CPUs.

The motherboard has a total of 18 RAM slots, which is three slots for each of three channels per CPU (9 slots total per CPU.)

I am hoping to run the following RAM configuration:

- CPU1:  three channels of: **<16GB, 16GB, empty>** - total 96GB
- CPU2:  three channels of: **<8GB, 8GB, 8GB>** - total 72GB
- Totalling **168GB**
- The 16GB chips are quad-rank, and the 8GB chips are dual-rank.  All RAM is Registered ECC.

My question is: is there any major problem with having mismatched RAM across the two CPUs?  This config does boot and provides the OS (Solaris 11.3) with the expected total of 168GB.  But might there be any underlying performance problems with this config?

To put another way: should this 168GB mismatched config generally be better than an evenly distributed 144GB config, assuming I can definitely use the extra RAM?  Or might the mismatched config be so slow as to not be preferable than more RAM?

In both scenarios the RAM will run at 800mhz, as my mobo won't run RAM faster than 800mhz when more than 4 ranks are used per channel

The reason I am going for this config is that I bought 6 x 16GB quad-rank chips, expecting that I could run: <16GB, 8GB, 8GB> in each of six channels, for a total of 192GB.  I thought this would work because the max for the mobo was listed as 288GB (16GB in every slot.)

It was only after I received and tested the RAM that I found it didn't work, and on re-reading the documentation I realised that the max config was only possible if all chips were dual-rank.  16GB dual-rank chips are prohibitively expensive.

I can achieve 144GB in an even distribution, configuring each channel as: <16GB, 8GB, empty>.  But after playing about I realised I could also achieve a working 168GB config, as described above.

This also means I could achieve 192GB if I purchased another 6 x 16GB chips (<16GB, 16GB, empty> in all channels), but I can't afford this at this time (even assuming I then sold all my 8GB chips.)

So I'd be grateful for confirmation as to whether the proposed mismatched config should work out OK, or if there might be hidden performance problems.  One difference I have noticed already is that the mobo takes noticeably longer to reach the BIOS screen with this mismatched config - nearly a minute, versus around 30 seconds.  I don't know if that's significant.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a NUMA motherboard. Each CPU *package* -- by which I mean a thing that plugs into a CPU socket, not a CPU "core" -- has its own memory controller. All of the memory attached to all of the CPUs is accessible to all of the CPUs.

However, in terms of the low-level interface between CPU and RAM, each CPU's bank of memory is separate from the other banks.

What that means is that any compatibility rules between memory DIMMs only apply within each memory bank. If DIMM A and DIMM B somehow won't work together in the same bank, but each works fine by itself, they may work fine in a NUMA system if they're in different CPUs' banks. More commonly: You could put 800 MHz DIMMs in one bank and 1333 MHz DIMMs in the other and they will each run at their own best speeds because *the memory controllers are separate*.

And there is no problem with having the two banks be of different total sizes.

Comment: Thanks very much for clearing that up, Jamie.  I had always thought NUMA was only applicable to many-CPU motherboards, I didn't realise until now it was part of the CPU architecture.  That's great to know.

Comment: Just fyi... the term "architecture" gets overloaded these days. Usually, "CPU architecture" would usually refers to the instruction set architecture. CPU-private memory banks, QP interconnects, etc., are more a matter of motherboard topology.

Comment: Understood, thanks. Yes I guess QPI is the key ingredient - the interconnect that facilitates NUMA? As an aside, thanks to your answer I've discovered a nice little Solaris userland tool - `lgrpinfo`. This shows me the NUMA groups (for me basically just two - though they show as leaves of a root group), and very helpfully shows, per group/CPU, how much RAM is installed, how much of it is currently in use, and Load and Latency figures.  Probably won't have huge day-to-day impact for me on a dual-CPU, but v. interesting nonetheless.  [Sample ouput here](https://pastebin.com/i5qqQwSr), FYI.

Answer (score 0):

RAM configs run at the speed of the slowest RAM stick 
For example, if I have 2 x 8GB RAM sticks, one at 3200 MHz and the other at 3600 MHz, the whole RAM config will only be clocked at 3200 MHz i.e the 3600 MHz stick will not achieve speed higher than 3200 MHz. 
This might be why the system slows down 
To the extent of my knowledge, different sizes of RAM on a motherboard don't usually give compatibility issues.The compatibility issues usually arise because people mix brands. As in, they use Corsair RAM with GSKILL etc. Mixing of brands can cause issues because each brand uses slightly different protocols. 
So, in short, as long as you don't mix brands and use the same type of RAM (DDR4/DDR3 and ECC) size won't hinder performance but speed might suffer as the speed of the slowest RAM stick, is now the speed at which ALL RAM sticks will run at. 
Hope this helped! 
EDIT: Note that mixing different brands give rise to issues like sudden unexpected shutdown which is the most common one.

Comment: Hi Sam, thanks very much for the fast response!  I forgot to mention that in both configs I will be running RAM at 800mhz - my mobo can do up to 1333mhz, but only if no more than 4 ranks per channel are in place.  So both the 144GB and 168GB config run at 800mhz.   (In any case my 16GB chips are only 1066mhz.)   But it's good to hear that in your view the mismatch across CPU won't cause an issue, thanks a lot.  Yes all chips are DDR3 ECC Registered, and all are Samsung brand.  Thanks again.